# AWS Python 3.7 Lambda using boto3: workmailmessageflow - UnknownServiceError

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, python-3.7

Following the sample code provided in the boto3 documentation for using the workmailmessageflow service

> import boto3
>
> client = boto3.client('workmailmessageflow')

triggers and UnknownServiceError: "Unknown service: 'workmailmessageflow'. Valid service names are..."

The boto3 version reported by AWS Lambda Python 3.7 is 1.9.221.  Any thoughts on why workmailmessageflow is not recognized?

Ref: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workmailmessageflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because workmailmessageflow first appeared in Boto3 [1.9.228](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.228/reference/services/workmailmessageflow.html).
You have to use a custom version of Boto3, either use a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) or package the latest version together with your code.